# How to put entire row as column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

For the following dataframe, I would like to change the column names with the row where the 1st column starts with a word or words. Here it's the 2nd row and the word `Company`. However, the row can be different like 1st, 5th or 10th row with different dataframe, and word can also be different like `Investment` and others.

```
structure(list(X1 = c("", "Company #", "Investments:"
), X2 = c("", "Type", ""), X3 = c("", "Reference", 
""), X4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X5= c("", "Footnotes", 
""), X6 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")

          X1             X2       X3        X4       X5       X6
    <chr>              <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>   <chr>    <chr>
1                                           NA               NA
2   Company #           Type   Reference    NA   Footnotes   NA
3   Investments:                            NA               NA
```

I'm thinking first to get the row number when the 1st column starts with a word/words, and then use that row number to change to column names, or maybe there are better ways to do that.

```
names(my_df)<- my_df[row_number,]
my_df <- my_df[-row_number,]
```

**Desired Output**

```
        Company #   Type   Reference    NA   Footnotes    NA
    <chr>           <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>   <chr>    <chr>
3   Investments:                         NA              NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
#row number of the first word in the first column
row_n <- min(which(nzchar(my_df[[1]])))
janitor::row_to_names(my_df, row_n)
```

output

```r
#     Company # Type Reference NA Footnotes   NA
#3 Investments:                NA           <NA>
```

Note that you will have non-unique column names (`NA`) if you do so. You can use `clean_names` to quickly remedy this.

Comment: Thanks @maël. Here it's the row == 2. However, row keeps changing with different dataframe.

Comment: Do you know in advance which row is it? if not you'll have to do manually

Comment: I am thinking if it's possible to get the row number when the 1st column starts with a word/words.

Comment: You can use `min(which(nzchar(my_df[[1]])))` to get the row number of the first non-empty value in the first variable

Comment: Thanks @mael. It works for all the edge cases. `clean_names` seems lowercase and put hyphen between words. Does it remove NA column name too?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
idx <- which(grepl('[^A-Za-z]', my_df$X1))[1]
colnames(my_df) <- my_df[idx, ]
my_df <- my_df[(idx + 1):nrow(my_df), ]
```

Output:

```
     Company # Type Reference NA Footnotes   NA
3 Investments:                NA           <NA>
```

This would check if any row begins with a letter, take the first occurrence as column names and keep only rows following it.

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
colnames(df) <- df[2,]
df <- df[-2,]
df
```

```
     Company # Type Reference NA Footnotes   NA
1                             NA           <NA>
3 Investments:                NA           <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `which` to get the row with the string like this:

```r
idx <- which("Company #" == my_df)
names(my_df) <- my_df[idx, ]
my_df <- my_df[-idx,]
my_df
#>      Company # Type Reference NA Footnotes   NA
#> 1                             NA           <NA>
#> 3 Investments:                NA           <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can look for your names using `which` on first column, then assign to colnames with `names` and finally delete that row. All this in base R:

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("", "Company #", "Investments:"
), X2 = c("", "Type", ""), X3 = c("", "Reference",""), X4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X5= c("", "Footnotes", ""), 
X6 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

row_names <- which(nchar(data.frame(df)[, "X1"]) > 1)[1]

names(df) <- df[row_names, ]
df[-c(row_names),]
```

Output:

```
     Company # Type Reference NA Footnotes   NA
1                             NA           <NA>
3 Investments:                NA           <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses a keyword in the first column to find the row, then makes sure it has no duplicate names with `make.unique` and no `NA`s (character or numeric) with `replace`.

```
key <- "Company #"

str <- as.character(dat[dat[,1] == key,][1,])

colnames(dat) <- make.unique(
  replace(str, str %in% "NA" | is.na(str), "Missing"), sep="_")
```

###### result

```
dat
     Company # Type Reference Missing Footnotes Missing_1
1                                  NA                <NA>
2    Company # Type Reference      NA Footnotes      <NA>
3 Investments:                     NA                <NA>
```

If the first non-empty cell should be picked use this

```
str <- as.character(dat[nchar(dat[,1]) != 0, ][1,])

colnames(dat) <- make.unique(
  replace(str, str %in% "NA" | is.na(str), "Missing"), sep="_")
```